# Silverlight -CRM2011 : The Currency Cannot Be null

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I use Silverlight o-data services to interact with crm 2011 from my application
When I try to save the data in the entity SalesOrder as follows:

```
Private void beginSave()
{
SalesOrder orderHeader = new SalesOrder();

orderHeader.TransactionCurrencyId = new EntityReference(){ Id = new Guid("77D695B5-ACB4-E111-97BC-00155D55B216"), LogicalName="transactioncurrency" };
orderHeader.AccountId = new EntityReference() { Id = new Guid(MyClassGeneralOrder.customerId), LogicalName = "account" };
orderHeader.Name = "My Name";
Money totalAmount = new Money(); Money totalAmountBase = new Money(); 
Money totalTaxe = new Money(); Money totalAmountLessFreight = new Money();
totalAmount.Value = (decimal)MyClassGeneralOrder.InvoiceTotal;
totalAmountBase.Value = (decimal)MyClassGeneralOrder.totalRetail;
totalTaxe.Value = (decimal)MyClassGeneralOrder.totalCharges;
totalAmountLessFreight.Value = (decimal)MyClassGeneralOrder.totalNet;
orderHeader.TotalAmount = totalAmount;
orderHeader.TotalAmount_Base = totalAmountBase;
orderHeader.TotalTax = totalTaxe;
orderHeader.TotalAmountLessFreight = totalAmountLessFreight;
orderHeader.Description = element.Name;
orderHeader.PriceLevelId = new EntityReference() { Id = new Guid("03C5C4CB-EBD0-E111-8140-00155D55B216"), LogicalName="pricelevel" };

_context.AddToSalesOrderSet(orderHeader);
_context.BeginSaveChanges(SaveCallback, orderHeader);

}


private void SaveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
_context.EndSaveChanges(result);

}
```

In my function EndSaveChanges (result), I receive this error message : : **« The Currency Cannot Be null ».**
I don't understand why, because my "orderHeader.TransactionCurrencyId" field is not null.

Comment: The fact you are using a hard coded Guid looks odd.

Comment: Really a bad idea to hardcode the Guid for the TransactionCurrencyId.  [This forum thread](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crm/thread/dc4ad6d3-b75b-449f-9df5-6b972d0abd43) illustrates how to retrieve the Guid for it programmatically.

Comment: Hi Sandta Walters , Like the Forum said the best way is   contact["transactioncurrencyid"] = new EntityReference("transactioncurrency", new Guid("9D2A622D-CD69-E011-9321-00155D042416"));

Comment: I Have one Default Currency in Crm 2011

Comment: That will break/need refactoring every single time you deploy this to a new server. You really, really, REALLY need to think about changing it. (IMO of course).

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that all of your other Currency fields are populated?

Any chance you have another plugin that is firing as a result of yours that is throwing the exception. That always seems to bite me. Try disabling all other plugins except for the one you're working on...

If you're still having issues, turn on crm server side tracing. You'll get much better error information. Use the CRM diagnostic tool to turn on trace logging: http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

Mostly your Guid is wrong and it's resulting in null. Make sure it's the correct GUID you are using or not. Run an advanced find against the entity and find the correct GUID. It's not a good idea to hard code the GUID. If you deploy your solutions to some other org it won't work.